# JCombobox Editable Java Programming

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

In my editable combo box. I want to allow the user
to type the name of a value in the `JComboBox` and it should display an appropriate error message if the desired value is not available.. (like a `JOptionPane`)
Do I need to use `getSelectedItem()` here?

Here's my code:

```
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

    import javax.swing.*;
    public class JTunes extends JFrame implements ItemListener{
    private JComboBox lyrics;
    private JTextField price;
    double sum = 0;
    public JTunes(){
        super("Lyrics");
        setSize(300,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        String[] lyrics1 = {"multiple", "data", "types", "used", "safely"};
        price = new JTextField(15);
         lyrics = new JComboBox(lyrics1);
         lyrics.setEditable(true);

         add(lyrics);
         add(price);
         lyrics.addItemListener(this);

    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
        String list = (String)lyrics.getSelectedItem();
            if(list.equals("multiple"))
                sum = 20;
            else if(list.equals("data"))
                sum = 30;
            else if(list.equals("types"))
                sum = 40;
            else if(list.equals("used"))
                sum = 50;
            else if(list.equals("safely"))
            sum = 60;


            price.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    }
}
```

Comment: Would `lyrics.getText()` and then comparing to `lyrics1` not work?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to allow the user to type the name of a value in the JComboBox and it should display an appropriate error message if the desired value is not available.

This makes no sense. The point of using a combo box it that the user can only select items if they exist in the list.

```
lyrics.setEditable(true);
```

Get rid of the above line of code and the user will only be able to select valid items.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you would simply want to see if the `jComboBox` 'contains' the text you're searching for. You should be able to use the following:

```
if(!jComboBox.contains("TEXT_TO_SEARCH") {    
    //Display error message accordingly. 
}
```

Comment: No. 
For example, while I type "hello" in the editable combobox, it should give me a message dialog telling that "Hello not found in the combobox". As there is no value of "hello" in the combobox

Comment: Right. And if the combo box does not contain the text you are searching for, then it can do just that. I'm sorry, if I was at my computer, I'd try to do it in NetBeans to test it out. I'm heading off for the night, but if you don't have an answer tomorrow, I will try to help you out more.

Comment: To answer your question about using getSelectedItem(), I don't think that will help you, because you're not actually selecting an item in the jComboBox.